# Installing Parallels Tools on NixOS

Tags: virtualization, parallels, nixos

How to *declaratively* install **Parallels Tools** on NixOS which is running as a guest in [Parallels for Mac](https://www.parallels.com)?

Answer (score 2):

I know you figured this out but for future searchers like myself:

Add the following to your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file:

```
nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;
hardware.parallels.enable = true;
```

Note however that at the moment [it appears to be broken](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/31882).